# Flutter: How to update channel token in AgoraRTCEngine with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, agora.io, videocall

I'm using AgoraRTCEngine in flutter to implement a videocall in my app and it succeeded.
The problem here is agora channel token expire in about 10 hours and it cant't be updated programmatcily via dart or flutter, it needs a server with backend to create channels and update tokens or update it from the website, but I don't have server now.
So, my question is "How to create Agora channels and update Agora channels token in flutter without any backend server?".

Comment: update it from the website

Comment: @dengST30 I can't update it every 11 hours when I release the app in app store, also updating it require updating the local variable in my app which is impossible when app in release mode

Answer (score 3):

**Update it from the website**, and make a repo in GitHub, put it there.

When app is in release mode, request it via GitHub's free api.

---

To update channel token in AgoraRTCEngine with flutter, you need generate the new token and deliver it to every device.

You can use flutter to call the `Agora.io`'s backend code to generate the new token, then spread the token via P2P protocol.

It guess it is a little hard.

Comment: Ok I'll try, but Agora.io doesn't allow me to generate new token with flutter, it only allows few languages like python and php

Comment: Flutter call python via lib FFI

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59697971/is-there-a-way-i-can-run-a-python-script-when-a-button-programmed-in-flutter-is